# For loop to delete item is impacting wrong list - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to create a list of dates that contains IDs and one that does not contain IDs. The for loop is acting on `without_ids` so why do the two `print with_ids` statement yield different results (column 1 is missing)?

```
import datetime
with_ids = [[u'ID 1', datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 13, 0, 0)], [u'ID 2', datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 13, 0, 0)]]
print with_ids
without_ids = with_ids
for x in without_ids:
    del x[0]
print "\n"
print with_ids
```

Output:

```
[[u'ID 1', datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 13, 0, 0)], [u'ID 2', datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 13, 0, 0)]]


[[datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 13, 0, 0)], [datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 13, 0, 0)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
without_ids = with_ids
```

Since `with_ids` references a list, `without_ids` will no reference **the same list**. Thus, when you delete items from `without_ids`, you are deleting the items from the underlying list object, which is the same list that `with_ids` is still referencing. So all your changes to the same object appear for all variables referencing the same object.

You have to create a copy of the list instead of copying the reference. Usually, you would do it like this:

```
without_ids = with_ids[:]
```

However, this will only copy the outer list, making it a shallow copy. Since your list contains list of lists, you would need a deep copy. And at that point, it becomes a bit tedious.

So instead of creating a copy, you could create a new list instead that just contains the elements *you want to keep*:

```
without_ids = [elem[1:] for elem in with_ids]
```

This is a list comprehension that will iterate over all elements in `with_ids` and just select all of that sub-lists element except the first (`elem[1:]` means start at the first index and take everything afterwards), and make a new list from those.

Answer (score 1):

In the statement

```
without_ids = with_ids
```

you are making `without_ids` refer to the same object as `with_ids` (this is known as *aliasing*).

**What can you do?** You can make a [**deep copy**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) (a simple copy `with_ids[:]` won't work, because it is a nested list):

```
import copy
without_ids = copy.deepcopy(with_ids)
```